# __Illuminate\Database\QueryException__

Tags: php, laravel

this error appeared to me when i click the add button in product page trying to add some data to the dataBase and other pages work fine the problem just in this page so i tryed some solations like
1 -

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan migrate
```

`2` - and i also tryed to change my database and didn't work
`3` - i run `php artisan migrate:rollback` and the migrated again `php artisan migrate` and it's not working
`4` - i check my `.env` and it's fine nothing wrong with it like below

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ecommerce4
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

`5` - i also add

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;


public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

full error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/store

Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback
C:\xampps\htdocs\ecommerce3\ecommerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
```

end error

the route

```
Route::prefix('product')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/store', [ProductController::class, 'StoreProduct'])->name('product.store');

});
```

end route

function in controller

public function StoreProduct(Request $request) {

```
$image = $request->file('product_thambnail');
$name_gen = hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
Image::make($image)->resize(917,1000)->save('upload/products/thambnail/'.$name_gen);
$save_url = 'upload/products/thambnail/'.$name_gen;

$product_id = Product::insertGetId([
    'brand_id' => $request->brand_id,
    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
    'subcategory_id' => $request->subcategory_id,
    'subsubcategory_id' => $request->subsubcategory_id,
    'product_name_en' => $request->product_name_en,
    'product_name_ar' => $request->product_name_ar,
    'product_slug_en' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $request->product_name_en)),
    'product_slug_ar' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $request->product_name_ar)),

    'product_code' => $request->product_code,
    'product_qty' => $request->product_qty,
    'product_tags_en' => $request->product_tags_en,
    'product_tags_ar' => $request->product_tags_ar,
    'product_size_en' => $request->product_size_en,
    'product_size_ar' => $request->product_size_ar,
    'product_color_en' => $request->product_color_en,
    'product_color_ar' => $request->product_color_ar,

    'selling_price' => $request->selling_price,
    'discount_price' => $request->discount_price,
    'short_descp_en' => $request->short_descp_en,
    'short_descp_ar' => $request->short_descp_ar,
    'long_descp_en' => $request->long_descp_en,
    'long_descp_ar' => $request->long_descp_ar,
    'hot_deals' => $request->hot_deals,
    'featured' => $request->featured,
    'special_offer' => $request->special_offer,
    'special_deals' => $request->special_deals,

    'product_thambnail' => $save_url,
    'status' => 1,
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),

]);
```

end function

migration part

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('brand_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('subcategory_id');
            $table->integer('subsubcategory_id');
            $table->string('product_name_en');
            $table->string('product_name_ar');
            $table->string('product_slug_en');
            $table->string('product_slug_ar');
            $table->string('product_code');
            $table->string('product_qty');
            $table->string('product_tags_en');
            $table->string('product_tags_ar');
            $table->string('product_size_en')->nullable();
            $table->string('product_size_ar')->nullable();
            $table->string('product_color_en');
            $table->string('product_color_ar');
            $table->string('selling_price');
            $table->string('discount_price')->nullable();
            $table->string('short_descp_en');
            $table->string('short_descp_ar');
            $table->string('long_descp_en');
            $table->string('long_descp_ar');
            $table->string('product_thambnail');
            $table->integer('hot_deals')->nullable();
            $table->integer('featured')->nullable();
            $table->integer('special_offer')->nullable();
            $table->integer('special_deals')->nullable();
            $table->integer('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

end migration

model part

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

end model part
CSS and HTML code

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('product.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start first Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Brand Select <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select name="brand_id" class="form-control" required="">
                                                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select Brand</option>
                                                @foreach ($brands as $brand)
                                                    <option value="{{ $brand->id }}">{{ $brand->brand_name_en }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                            @error('brand_id')
                                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Category Select <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select name="category_id" class="form-control" required="">
                                                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select Category</option>
                                                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->category_name_en }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                            @error('category_id')
                                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>SubCategory Select <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select name="subcategory_id" class="form-control" required="">
                                                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select SubCategory</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @error('subcategory_id')
                                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                            </div> {{-- end first Row --}}







                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start second Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>SubSubcategory Select <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select name="subsubcategory_id" class="form-control" required="">
                                                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Select SubSubcategory</option>

                                            </select>
                                            @error('subsubcategory_id')
                                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Name En <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_name_en" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_name_en')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Name AR <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_name_ar" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_name_ar')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}
                            </div> {{-- end second Row --}}





                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start thered Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Code <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_code" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_code')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Quantity <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_qty" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_qty')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Tag En <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_tags_en" class="form-control" value="Lorem,Ipsum,Amet" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_tags_en')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}
                            </div> {{-- end thered Row --}}








                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start Fourth Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Tag Ar <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_tags_ar" class="form-control" value="Lorem,Ipsum,Amet" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_tags_ar')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Size En <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_size_en" class="form-control" value="Small,Midium,Large" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_size_en')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Size Ar <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_size_ar" class="form-control" value="Small,Midium,Large" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_size_ar')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}
                            </div> {{-- end Fourth Row --}}






                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start Five Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Color En <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_color_en" class="form-control" value="red,black,green" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_color_en')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Color Ar <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_color_ar" class="form-control" value="red,black,green" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_color_ar')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Selling Price <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="selling_price" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('selling_price')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}
                            </div> {{-- end Five Row --}}







                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start Sex Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Product Discount Price <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" name="discount_price" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('discount_price')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Main Thambnail <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="file" name="product_thambnail" class="form-control" onchange="mainThamUrl(this)" required="">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('product_thambnail')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror
                                        <img src="" id="mainThmb" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-4"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Multiple Image <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="file" name="multi_img[]" class="form-control" multiple="" id="multiImg" required>
                                        </div>
                                        @error('multi_img')
                                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                        @enderror

                                        <div class="row" id="preview_img"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}
                            </div> {{-- end Sex Row --}}






                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start Seven Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-6"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Short Description En <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <textarea name="short_descp_en" id="textarea" class="form-control" required placeholder="Short Description English"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-6"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Short Description Ar <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <textarea name="short_descp_ar" id="textarea" class="form-control" required placeholder="Short Description Arabic"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}
                            </div> {{-- end Sex Row --}}







                            <div class="row"> {{-- Start Seven Row --}}
                                <div class="col-md-6"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Long Description En <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <textarea id="editor1" name="long_descp_en" rows="10" cols="80" required>Long Description English.</textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}

                                <div class="col-md-6"> {{-- Start col --}}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>Long Description Ar <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <textarea id="editor2" name="long_descp_ar" rows="10" cols="80" required>Long Description Arabic.</textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> {{-- end col --}}
                            </div> {{-- end Sex Row --}}







                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <hr>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="hot_deals" id="checkbox_2" value="1">
                                            <label for="checkbox_2">Hot Deals</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" id="checkbox_3" value="1">
                                            <label for="checkbox_3">Featured</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="special_offer" id="checkbox_4" value="1">
                                            <label for="checkbox_4">Special Offer</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="special_deals" id="checkbox_5" value="1">
                                            <label for="checkbox_5">Special Deals</label>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-xs-right">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary mb-5" value="Add Product">
                        </div>
                </form>
```

can any one help me sorry for my poor english

Comment: The most important part of your question is missing, the actual code that causes this issue (the query itself).

Comment: Run the code in a debugger. Barring that, extract a [mcve] and include that in your question. Also, having the full stack trace would help.

Comment: @MuhammedJack, can you post the controller function for `/product/store`?

Comment: As @BagusTesa said, put the store method code so we can check it.

Comment: I added it and added migration and model with it

Comment: @MuhammedJack just to be sure, how long the `long_descp_en` and `long_descp_ar` you did send? laravel by default sets `varchar` column to allow only 255 characters - [see this part](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php#L39). you might hit this limit somewhere.

Comment: It's too long so I changed it to (TEXT) in my database

Comment: @BagusTesa i also tryed small text and also not working

Comment: @MuhammedJack truth to be told, i'm just doing guesswork. i compared your migration, controller, and html input fields but they seem to checks out (no missing input). my next guess was on the description field given how laravel treats `varchar`. to be honest, it would be difficult to proceed without the error message from your `QueryException`.

Comment: @BagusTesa The problem is that it does not give me the exact location of the error to solve it, and I also searched for the solution on the sites and no solution worked with it, so now I will delete the entire product page and do everything again